# how can I have two different tab widgets or fragmentpagers

Tags: android, android-fragments, tabs, android-actionbar

I have a class like this, that allows me to have actionbar tabs that always display.

```
 public static class AppSectionsPagerAdapter extends  FragmentPagerAdapter
{
    public AppSectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm)
    {
        super(fm);
    }
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int i)
    {
        switch (i)
        {
        case 0:
            return new MainFrag();
        case 1:
            return new Dummy0();
        case 2:
            return new Dummy1();
        case 3:
            return new Dummy2();
        case 4:
            return new Settings();
        default:
            Fragment frag = new Error_Fragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            errorcode = "-5";
            args.putInt(errorcode, i + 1);
            frag.setArguments(args);
            return frag;
        }
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount()
    {
        return 5;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position)
    {
        return tabnames[position];
    }
}
```

However , I would like in one of the fragments to have another tab bar at the bottom to change between different modes like on the iphone the camera has a tab at the bottom to change between still shots and video. How can I have both tab bars display?

thanks very much problem solved!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use other library like :

[PagerSlidingTabStrip](https://github.com/astuetz/PagerSlidingTabStrip)

or if you want to have a google one you can try:

[SlidingTabsBasic](https://developer.android.com/samples/SlidingTabsBasic)

or you can use [fragmentTabHost](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentTabHost.html) or [TabHost](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TabHost.html).

put those tabs in your layout at the bottom and you are done :-)

I think you can also do it with 2 simple buttons and a framelayout that contains a fragment and change according to buttons click.